# XSLT: How to get the first record based on condition

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm new to this XSLT and trying to fix some issue.Could you please help me in resolving this one.

Actually I have a raw data which will have the information about scan rejected files. Each rejected item will log info. in 3 elements in raw data i.e i)ScanRejected ii) ScanInitiated iii) CardSupplier. 
I'm trying to process this raw data and put it in XML in a formatted way. While processing each record every time if I find `<ScanRejected>` element then I want to access `<CardSupplier>` element to get the `CardNumber`. it means I need to access **ONLY** immediate previous `CardSupplier` element.

Here in this case I need to get card number as
`<CardNumber t="String">##############0251</CardNumber>` 
**NOT**
`<CardNumber t="String">##############1111</CardNumber>`

### **INPUT XML**:

```
    <ScanRejected>
      <Validity t="String">NotValidated</Validity>
      <EventID t="String">ScanRejected</EventID>
    </ScanRejected>
    <ScanInitiated>
      <EventID t="String">ScanInitiated</EventID>
      <TransactionReference t="String"></TransactionReference>
    </ScanInitiated>
    <CardSupplier>
      <CardNumber t="String">##############0251</CardNumber>
      <CardPosition t="String">Inserted</CardPosition>
      <CardValid t="Boolean">True</CardValid>
      <EventID t="String">CardAccepted</EventID>
    </CardSupplier>
    <ScanRejected>
      <Validity t="String">NotSupported</Validity>
      <EventID t="String">ScanRejected</EventID>
    </ScanRejected>
    <ScanInitiated>
      <EventID t="String">ScanInitiated</EventID>
      <TransactionReference t="String"></TransactionReference>
    </ScanInitiated>
    <CardSupplier>
      <CardNumber t="String">##############1111</CardNumber>
      <CardPosition t="String">Inserted</CardPosition>
      <CardValid t="Boolean">True</CardValid>
      <EventID t="String">CardAccepted</EventID>
    </CardSupplier>
    <ScanRejected>
      <Validity t="String">NotScanned</Validity>
      <EventID t="String">ScanRejected</EventID>
    </ScanRejected>
    <ScanInitiated>
      <EventID t="String">ScanInitiated</EventID>
      <TransactionReference t="String"></TransactionReference>
    </ScanInitiated>
    <CardSupplier>
      <CardNumber t="String">##############2345</CardNumber>
      <CardPosition t="String">Inserted</CardPosition>
      <CardValid t="Boolean">True</CardValid>
      <EventID t="String">CardAccepted</EventID>
    </CardSupplier>
```

### **Desidered OUTPUT**:

```
    -<Tran>
      <TranName>ScanRejected</TranName>
      <CardNumber>##############0251</CardNumber>
    </Tran>
    -<Tran>
      <TranName>ScanRejected</TranName>
      <CardNumber>##############1111</CardNumber>
    </Tran>
    -<Tran>
      <TranName>ScanRejected</TranName>
      <CardNumber>##############2345</CardNumber>
    </Tran>
```

### ** My XSLT

```
<xsl:template name="ScanTemplate">
  <xsl:variable name="x" select ="Content/*[1]" />
  <Tran>
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$x/EventID='ScanRejected'">
        <TranName>ScanRejected</TranName>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <CardNumber> </CardNumber>
  </Tran>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you post the XSL-T if you already have one?

Comment: Thanks  @potame , Please see the template which I have written....          `<xsl:template name="ScanTemplate">
    <xsl:variable name="x" select ="Content/*[1]" />
    <Tran>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$x/EventID='ScanRejected'">
          <TranName>ScanRejected</TranName>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <CardNumber>
        
      </CardNumber>
    </Tran>
  </xsl:template>`

Comment: According to SO rules, you should post your code in your question, not as a comment. I provided you with an answer below.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us a **complete** XML input and XSLT. -- **Hint**: you need to be using a template that *matches* something - not a *named* template (which you don't appear to be calling, so it's probably not doing anything).

Comment: It would also be nice to accept the answer to your question (if it is correct), e.g.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269306/xslt-concatenate-and-select-the-element

Comment: @potame, Did you get a chance to see the updated data, I would really appreciate your help in this regard. Thanks

Comment: Yes I have, but for the moment I can't do anything more. We are still lacking some info, e.g. the root element of your input XML, how and where is the `ScanTemplate` called. And also what is the problem with what you tried below? What do you get as a result (nothing, error message, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you have tried so far, but something like that should work properly, and at least give you a clue to do what you want:

```
<!-- assuming the root element of the XML is "root" -->
<xsl:template match="root">
   <out>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ScanRejected"/>
   </out>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ScanRejected">
    <Tran>
        <TranName>ScanRejected</TranName>
        <CardNumber><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::CardSupplier[1]/CardNumber" /></CardNumber>
    </Tran>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Tried with your code but this seems to be not working.

Comment: @Sandeep Sangshetty is it possible to have more information :) ? What is not working? How did you integrate this code snippet in your stylesheet? Is there an error message?

Comment: the content which I have added over here is sample one because I can't  post my actual confidential code, can you pls let me know if there is any other way I can share that information with you?

Comment: Well, we don't require you to send us your confidential data, rather a minimal and representative set of elements to help you solve your issue. It should be enough to help you, and help other persons encountering similar issues that's why it is preferable to edit your post so that I can update my answer.